# Odd behavior with Button, Command and canExecute

Tags: c#, wpf, button, command

I have a simple button:

```
<Button Content="Print" Command="{Binding PrintCommand}"/>
```

...with a command:

```
private RelayCommand _printCommand;
public ICommand PrintCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_printCommand == null)
        {
            _printCommand = new RelayCommand(param => Print(),
                                             () => (Files != null && Files.Count > 0));
        }

        return _printCommand;
    }
}
```

It is enabled only when the `Files` collection is either not null or has some items in it.  Here's the collection:

```
private ObservableCollection<RecordModel> _files;
public ObservableCollection<RecordModel> Files
{
    get { return _files; }
    set
    {
        if (_files == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _files = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Files");
    }
}
```

The collection is bound to a `ListView` in the window.  Thus far, nothing special... and here's where the odd behavior comes in...

If I have enough items in the collection to have `ListView`'s `ScrollBar` to show, then my button is shown as `Enabled`, which is good.  If I have no items, then it's `Disabled`, which is also good.  However, if I have just enough items to fill a portion of the visible `ListView`, without triggering the appearance of the `ScrollBar`, then my button shows as `Disabled`. If I focus on any control, including the button itself, then it pops-up as `Enabled`.  I've no idea what's going on.  At first, I thought it might have been a button template I was using, so I got rid of it and kept the button with the default setup, yet the odd behavior remained.

Any ideas what's going on?

Here's the `RelayCommand` class.  I'm not sure if a problem could be within it, but that's what I've been using for a while:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute; 
    readonly Func<bool> _canExecute; 

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { } 
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<bool> canExecute) 
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }
        _execute = execute; 
        _canExecute = canExecute; 
    } 

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) 
    { 
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(); 
    } 

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged 
    { 
        add 
        { 
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; 
        } 
        remove 
        { 
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; 
        } 
    } 

    public void Execute(object parameter) 
    { 
        _execute(parameter); 
    } 
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here's how I populate my collection.

```
public FileManagerViewModel()
{
    LoadCollection();
}

private void LoadCollection()
{
    Task task = new Task(() =>
    {
        Files = DbWorker.GetFiles();
    });
    task.Start();
}
```

Here's how I bind the collection to the `ListView`:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:FileManagerViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Files}" x:Key="GroupedFiles">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="RepNum"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedFiles}}">
    ...
</ListView
```

**EDIT:**

Hmm, I don't know if this is it or how it could be causing it (especially with the whole `ScrollBar` situation), but when I don't use the `Task` to update my collection, I don't experience this behavior.  Of course, I then have to deal with hanging due to a lengthy operation.  Not sure how I can remedy this, considering I don't want to block the UI thread.  I even tried this and it didn't change anything:

```
var temp = new ObservableCollection<RecordModel>();
Task task = new Task(() =>
{
    temp = DbWorker.GetFiles();
});
task.ContinueWith((result) =>
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new Action(() =>
        {
            Files = temp;
        }));
});
task.Start();
```

But I don't see an issue with properties not being updated.  I've checked and all the properties update as needed.  It's just something with that little hang in the status update of `CanExecute` that only updates by focus change (in this scenario).

Just based on what I know, it seems as if there's an issue between threads and Commands... hmm.  Every time I manually give UI element a focus by clicking on, Commands update (or so it appears).  This also happens if ScrollBar appears or dissapears.  But then other UI elements don't do anything, such as text.

Comment: I have an idea what this may be. Can you post your relevant XAML and show how/where you create your view model and where/how you set the Files property?

Comment: @MichaelGunter Which part of the XAML?  There's a lot, so I don't want to flood with code.  I posted the ViewModel portion that shows how I set my collection.  What sort of idea do you have?

Comment: Could you also post the part of the xaml where you are binding the IsEnabled property for you button to the collection size.

Comment: @ankhuri Enabled/Disabled is handled by the Command.  That code is already posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as I see it your command just doesn`t know that it is related to `Files` collection. So `Files` is changed, it`s setter is called, your `ListView` is updated because it is bound to that collection and reacts to PropertyChanged. But command is not tied directly to it so it just sits there undisturbed, drinking coffee or whatever. Only when UI starts changing the system calls CanExecute and it starts working. So I think the simple solution here can be to tie `Files` to command.

You can do it directly it the setter (because you know that command is dependent on collection):

```
public ObservableCollection<RecordModel> Files
{
    get { return _files; }
    set
    {
        if (_files == value) return;

        _files = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Files");
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
}
```

Or you can do it right when you load the collection (for example if you know that`s the only operation that affects collection size):

```
task.ContinueWith((result) =>
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new Action(() =>
        {
            Files = temp;
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }));
});
```

**Note**: I used `InvalidateRequerySuggested` as simplest way to invalidate command, but it`s a bit of overkill. Other `ICommand` implementations use different techniques to do that (for example Telerik`s DelegateCommand has custom `InvalidateCanExecute` method). So this part can be further improved.

Comment: First one didn't work.  Second one did.  Thank you so much! :)  I'll look into the ways of improving it, but it does the trick for now.  Is there a way of assigning this within XAML?  Maybe through target property?

Comment: For the first one to work you still need to set `Files` in UI thread for notifications events to be called properly (like you do in ContinueWith task). More XAML-oriented approach can be to bind `Files` to button\`s `CommandParameter` and make your CanExecute method take and process it. But that won\`t solve your initial issue as you\`ll still need to give focus to some control for button to pick up new IsEnabled value. @B.K.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Thank you for providing me with more information, it is incredibly valuable to me.

Comment: For me the second option with Dispatcher also worked. I guess in my case problem was that the property CanExecute() return was called from a different thread. If I understand this correctly Dispatcher will pass the call to the UI thread and then binding works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I will not be able to comment on why this design is not working because it is not clear from the code provided how your command is handling the enabling of the button. But the way I would do this is the following:
In my viewmodel class I would have a public property IsPrintAllowed.

```
private bool _isPrintAllowed;

public bool IsPrintAllowed{
get{ return _isPrintAllowed;}
set{_isPrintAllowed = value;
RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsPrintAllowed)}
```

The CollectionChanged event of the Files collection would evaluate IsPrintAllowed Property.

```
Files.CollectionChanged += EvaluateIsPrintAllowed;


private void EvaluateIsPrintAllowed()
{
     IsPrintAllowed = Files != null && Files.Count > 0;
}
```

And in the xaml I would bind the IsEnabled property of the button to IsPrintAllowed.

```
<Button Content="Print" Command="{Binding PrintCommand}" IsEnabled = {Binding IsPrintAllowed}/>
```

Comment: I think you should read this if my code is unclear: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx  Scroll down to RelayCommand.

Comment: In that case, is the CanExecuteChanged event being raised when you are setting value for CanExecute in your command?

Comment: Well, it appears so.  `PrintCommand.CanExecuteChanged += CanExecuteChanged; private void CanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("sender: {0}, e: {1}", sender, e)); }` fires off.  But it also fires off for other command CanExecute statuses within the view.